# How to turn off blackberry device

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Is it possible to turn off Blackberry Device programmatically  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [requestPowerOff()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Device.html#requestPowerOff%28boolean%29) method in the Device class.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no "clear" solution for that. Take a look on this thread: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Turn-on-off-Bluetooth-programmatically/td-p/489615

But you can use key injection to turn device off. It works quickly enough, so from the user perspective that device is just switched off.